# Precedence of the operators & and | in Scala

Tags: scala

In the book "Programming in Scala" (Martin Odersky, 2nd edition) they give this *operator precedence table* (*not complete here*):

```
* / %
+ -
:
= !
< >
&
^
|
```

So that if the first character of an operator has a higher position in this table that the first character of another operator, the former operator is evaluated first.

According to that this code should print out `yy`, but it prints out `x`:

```
def x() = { print('x'); true }
def y() = { print('y'); true }

x || y && y        // prints `x` but should `yy`
```

My understanding is that if **&** is higher in the table that **|**, it must be evaluated first. It is like ***** has precedence over **+**, so in `x + y * y`, the last statement is evalueted first.

---

**EDIT**:

Also look at this code

```
def x() = { print('x'); 1 }
def y() = { print('y'); 3 }

x == x + y * y        // xxyy
```

Look like it evaluates them from left to right but "solves" them according to the table.

Comment: Because in the second case `x` and `y` results to `Int` and in case of Boolean it uses different evaluation model

Comment: `|` is not the same as `||` and the book doesn't give the precedence for logical operands. I assume the same precedence is used as for Java where `&&` is still higher than `||` but then there's short-circuiting in work here. Java would also print the 'x'.

Answer (score 3):

Raw version:

```
x || y && y
```

With precedence applied:

```
x || (y && y)
```

(Note, if the precedence was reversed it would be `(x || y) && y`.)

Now, you are expecting `(y && y)` to get evaluated before `x`, but Scala always evaluates left-to-right (see §6.6 of the [language spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf)). And, as others have mentioned, `||` is a short-circuiting operator, so the the second operand is not even evaluated if the first operand returns true.

Another way to think of it is as a two method calls, where the second operand of both is pass-by-name:

```
or (x, and(y, y))

def or(a: Boolean, b: => Boolean): Boolean = if (a) true else b
def and(a: Boolean, b: => Boolean): Boolean = if (!a) false else b
```

Under the left-to-right evaluation model, `x` is ALWAYS evaluated first, then maybe `y` twice.

If you haven't already done so, you could follow Martin Odersky's functional programming course on [Coursera](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-003/class/index) where he talks about this very subject in lecture 1 or 2.

Your second example is equivalent to

```
add(x, mult(y, y))

def add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
def mult(a: Int, b: Int) = a * b
```

`x` is always evaluated first, then `y`, twice.

Comment: The key misunderstanding here is that the OP is assuming that *operator precedence* corresponds to *order of evaluation*, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

It prints `x` because `x()` call returns `true` and in case of `||` logic operator if left part return true, the right part is not computed. To compute it use `|` then, even if left part is `true` the right part will be evaluated

**Updated**

Example with boolean is not good, because in case with booleans so called "short-circuit" evaluation is used and scalac won't even look at the second part of `or` expression if the left part is `true`. Think of this operation like:

```
def || (a: => Boolean) = ???
```

Comment: I know that, but it does not explain. For me it should not look at **x** before solving **y**'s.

Comment: @Graduate explains, it's not a good example in general cause boolean operators use short-circuit evaluation in the scalac. Scala just won't look at the right part if left is true